# How to retrieve user input in android?

Tags: android

I have an edit text and i want to get user input and hold that input as a String. Here is my code:

```
protected TextView soru;
protected EditText kcevap;
protected Button gonder;
protected String input;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    kcevap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kcevap);
    gonder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gonder);
    gonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            input = kcevap.getText().toString().trim();
        }
    });
    soru = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soru);
}
```

my xml:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1"
    android:id="@+id/soru"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:textSize="60dp" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/kcevap"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="137dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gonder"
    android:id="@+id/gonder"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/kcevap"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="#010000"
    android:background="#12bfda" />
```

Edited for a new solution. Thanks for your help! Actually it says that

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

Comment: What have you tried? Reading the value of the edittext? And which problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables for the class:

```
private EditText myEditText;
private Button gonder;
```

In `OnCreate()` (assuming you are in `Activity` class) add:

```
myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
gonder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gonder);

gonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = myEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        //you have your string, do as you want with it 
    }
});
```

where `myedittext` is id of your `EditText` in layout.

Comment: Actually it says that "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button"

Comment: @EmreŞen Edit your question and add your code from class and XML. I will help you fix it.

Comment: @EmreŞen Change your `TextView` to `Button` component (this one with `android:id="@+id/gonder"`)

Answer (score 0):

As you know you mentioned in your xml that textview is clickable.
So

```
EditText kcevap;
 Textview gonder;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     kcevap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kcevap);
     gonder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gonder);
     gonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        input = kcevap.getText().toString().trim();
    }
});

}
```

Comment: If he wants button change gonder textview to button simple in xml

Comment: By the way he mentioning in his xml that textview is clickable.

Comment: I want that when someone write something and click the button i want to hold what he wrote...

Comment: @EmreŞen look in comment under my answer; you can use `Button` or clickable `TextView`, but you must decide what you want, because in Java code you are expecting `Button`, while you have `TextView` in XML;

Comment: @DamianKozlak aaah okay! i finally see the problem! Thank you so much sir!